# In Visual Studio, the UIButton. cs source file code under UnityEngine is recognized as text rather than code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I open Visual Studio in the Unity engine to write C# scripts, in which I declare a UnityEngine

The `Button` class in UI space, when I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left mouse</kbd> click on this class, I can go to a `Button.cs` file to view its partial source code.

There is a lock on the right side of the tab of this file, which does not allow me to modify the source code of the file. This is normal.

But when I close this tab and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left mouse button</kbd> to click on the `Button` class again, the code in the `Button.cs` file that enters becomes completely white, as if it is only recognized as text rather than code.

I can even delete and modify these codes. When I <kbd>right-click</kbd> on the tab and click `Open folder`, it will display

> The folder may have been deleted or have insufficient permissions

Why is this so?

[image]

[image]

If I close VisualStudio and restart, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left click</kbd> on the `Button` class, the code for `Button.cs` will again be recognized and displayed in color.

After closing `Button.cs` and clicking again, it will not be recognized and displayed as white.

Comment: In your second picture what does the text next to `Button.cs` say? (the one within `[???]`) ... just a guess but the first time it basically decompiles the class from the Unity source - second might be a cached version of that

Comment: Are you using VS' navigate-to-disassembly feature - or is it using a local copy of the Unity source-files derived from SourceLink - or even sources directly embedded within a `.nupkg`?

Comment: Another (and more likely explanation) is that you have a corrupted VS install - or you have a VS Extension installed that's breaking the code-editor? Does it happen if you use the Repair button in VS Installer and/or [use Safe Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022)?

Comment: You can try to use Visual Studio Installer to repair Visual Studio. You can also run Visual Studio with administrator privileges to troubleshoot issues with insufficient permissions. In addition to this, you can also start Visual Studio using safe mode

Comment: @derHugo it is [External sources].After I updated and fixed Visual Studio, even recognized code will display this [external source] tag. I think you make sense, but I don't know how to fix it. My current Unity version is `2022.2.17f1c`, and I have found that creating a project with long-term support version `2021.3.23f1c1` will not have this issue. If I upgrade to another long-term support version `2022.3.17f1c`, I will still have this issue. However, for some reasons, I am unable to rollback my version:<

Comment: don't do versions without any version control of your project (git, or minimum a backup) .. changing version also includes changing package versions and sometimes automatic API code changes

Comment: @Dai I tried, but it didn't seem to work. My current Unity version is 2022.2.17f1c, and I have found that creating a project with long-term support version 2021.3.23f1c1 will not have this issue. If I upgrade to another long-term support version 2022.3.17f1c, I will still have this issue. However, for some reasons, I am unable to rollback my version:<

Comment: @WenbinGeng I have tried before, but it didn't work:<

Comment: If you confirm that the issue is caused by UnityEngine, you can provide feedback to the official website of UnityEngine.

Comment: @WenbinGeng Got it.:>